# ANTLR - parameters

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have started to learn ANTLR and i was looking at the example grammars.
I found the CSV grammar quite interesting:

```
grammar CSV; 

file: hdr row+ ; 
hdr : row ; 

row : field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n' ; 

field 
    : TEXT 
    | STRING 
    | 
; 

TEXT   : ~[,\n\r"]+ ; 
STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ;
```

Is it possible to tell antlr that every row should have the same length as the hdr?

In my application i would need such a mechanism. To put it simply Id like to read in a INT variable contaniing the length N of an array and after it N values. Somthing like this:

```
// example-Input I want to parse 
A = 3 
a_0 = 2 
a_1 = 5        //there have to be exactly A = 3 a_ entries
a_2 = 3
```

Is this possible with antlr? And if not directly in the grammar, can it be dione afterwards somehow?

Comment: It can (and should) be done afterwards. It adds semantics to your application, and semantics should be a concern separated from the parsing.

Comment: You can use a Parse Tree Visitor/Listener to traverse the parse tree. Collect the information from header, then assert that the number of row+ (RowContext) complies with this number.

Comment: Thank you very much so far. So the term i was looking for was "semantic predicate" .
It seems that https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Semantic+Predicates should help me?
Anyways if you could give me an example of how to do it in the CSV-grammar it would be rly helpful.